# Count occurrence´s of Element in numpy array (list)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, counting

i am working on this very simple code to learn about python. My goal is, to have a graph of a binomial distribution that may appear when I roll two dices many many times.
For that I wrote these lines of code so far:

```
    import random
    import numpy
    
    class Dice:
        def roll(self):
            first = random.randint(1, 6)
            return first


    class Dice2:   
        def roll(self):
            second = random.randint(1, 6)
            return second
   
   
    storage1 = []
    storage2 = []
    for rolling in range(10, 0, -1):
        dice = Dice()
        storage1.append(dice.roll())
        storage2.append(dice.roll())
    
    list1 = numpy.array((storage1)) + numpy.array((storage2))
    
    print(list1)
    
    
    x = 5
    count = 0
    
    for dice in list1:
        if(dice == x):
            count = count + 1
        print(count1)
```

So what I am trying to do here, is to output the count of an Element, in this case x = 5, in other words, how many times I will throw the 5 when I roll 2 dices.
Especially the last part:

```
 list1 = numpy.array((storage1)) + numpy.array((storage2))
    
    print(list1)
    
    
    x = 5
    count = 0
    
    for dice in list1:
        if(dice == x):
            count = count + 1
        print(count1)
```

doesn't seem to work, the output is something I don't understand, it outputs something like this:

```
[ 2  7  7  8  7  4  7  9 10 10] 
  
#This is the output from the line: list1 = numpy.array((storage1)) + numpy.array((storage2))
# so this part I understand, it is the addition of dice1 and dice2, like wished

1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1

# This is the Output from the loop and finally the print(count1)
```

I would like to know, how can I store the number of occurrences, any number from 2 to 12 (from rolling two dices) does occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple modification of your code to get counts of roll values.  If you specifically wanted to make use of Numpy let me know.

**Code**

```
from random import randint  # only using randint so only import it
import numpy as np          # not needed

class Dice:
    def roll(self):
        return randint(1, 6)

frequencies = [0]*13        # array to hold results of dice roll 
                            # will use frequencies 2 to 12)

dice = Dice()
remaining_rolls = 10000     # number of remaining rolls 
while remaining_rolls > 0:
    roll = dice.roll() + dice.roll() # roll sum
    frequencies[roll] += 1   # increment array at index roll by 1
    remaining_rolls -= 1
    
print(frequencies)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 0, 272, 583, 829, 1106, 1401, 1617, 1391, 1123, 863, 553, 262]
```

**Using List Comprehension** as an alternative to while loop

```
frequencies = [0]*13 
for roll in [dice.roll() + dice.roll() for _ in range(10000)]:
    frequencies[roll] += 1
print(frequencies) # Simpler Output
```

**Explanation**

Assignment:

```
frequencies = [0]*13
```

Creates an array with 13 elements, with index from 0 to 12 initially filled with zeros.

The sum of each dice roll is a number between 2 and 12 (i.e. 11 values)

To increment a count of a roll we use:

```
 frequencies[roll] += 1
```

This is [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for:

```
frequencies[roll] = frequencies[roll] + 1
```

For instance, if roll = 5 we add 1 to frequencies[5]
This increments the count for the number of times the roll is 5.

Two bins are always zero:

```
frequencies[0] and frequencies[1]
```

This is because 2 <= roll <= 12 so we never increment bins 0 and 1.

Comment: Nice, thats pretty simple and elegant, thank you.. just some more questions: why are there 2 zeros in the output?  And how does the  increment array at index roll by 1 work? in other words, what kind of process is going on in frequencies[roll] += 1  ?

Comment: @BenjaminDiLorenzo--hi Benjamin.  I added some explanation.  Does this answer your questions?

Comment: Yes it mainly does. I just dont know what kind of process/operator is implied via >>> frequencies = [0]*13  ? Does this create a list with a given index? where can I find out more about this syntax?

Comment: @BenjaminDiLorenzo--[this shows](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/50400397.html) three ways of creating a list of length n with a repeated value.  In our case, the length is 13 and the value is 0 and we are using the 3rd method.